# Why do I get "SyntaxError: Expected token ']'"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script to make a 'night mode' on a website.

Whenever I try to run the script, I get the error

> "SyntaxError: Expected token ']'" on line 9.

That line says:

```
this.pageElements[0] = ['element': document.body, 'background': ['day': '#f1f1f1', 'night': '#0e0e0e']];
```

Why is it not working?

This is the full code:

```
window.nightMode = {};

//Functions
nightMode.init = function () {
    this.pageElements = [];

    //Format: ['element': Element, 'background': ['day': Day background color, 'night': Night background color], 'text': ['day': Day text color, 'night': Night text color]];
    this.pageElements[0] = {
        'element': document.body,
        'background': {
            'day': '#f1f1f1',
            'night': '#0e0e0e'
        }
    };
    this.pageElements[1] = {
        'element': document.getElementById('yt-masthead-container'),
        'background': {
            'day': '#fff',
            'night': '#000'
        }
    };
    this.pageElements[2] = {
        'element': document.getElementById('search-btn'),
        'background': {
            'day': '#fff',
            'night': '#000'
        }
    };
    this.pageElements[3] = {
        'element': document.getElementById('masthead-search-terms'),
        'background': {
            'day': '#fff',
            'night': '#000'
        },
        'text': {
            'day': '#666',
            'night': '#999'
        }
    };


    this.isNight = false;
}

nightMode.setNight = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.pageElements.length; i++) {
        this.pageElements[i].element.style.background = this.pageElements[i].background.night
        if (this.pageElements[i].text) {
            this.pageElements[i].element.style.color = this.pageElements[i].text.night
        }
    }
    alert('Night mode');

    this.isNight = true;
}

nightMode.setDay = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.pageElements.length; i++) {
        this.pageElements[i].element.style.background = this.pageElements[i].background.day
        if (this.pageElements[i].text) {
            this.pageElements[i].element.style.color = this.pageElements[i].text.day
        }
    }
    alert('Day mode');

    this.isNight = false;
}

nightMode.toggle = function () {
    if (this.isNight) {
        this.setDay();
    } else {
        this.setNight();
    }
}


//Startup Code
nightMode.init();

nightMode.toggle();
```

Comment: Update to: `this.pageElements[0] = {'element':document.body, 'background':['day':'#f1f1f1', 'night':'#0e0e0e']};`

Comment: Probably because that is invalid, arrays don't have keys and values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are ordered lists. Objects are key:value pairs.

You are trying to put the body of object literals inside array literals.

Use object literals `{}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Object literals (key/value pairs) are enclosed in `{}`, not `[]`; the latter is only used for arrays (objects whose keys are all non-negative indexes). So it should be:

```
this.pageElement[0] = {
    element: document.body,
    background: {
        day: '#f1f1f1',
        night: '#0e0e0e'
    }
};
```